# jqGrid: loadonce option disable the total parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

When i'm using the parameter `loadonce: true` in my jqGrid, when I'm getting this json result:

`{ page: 1, records: 10, rows: […], total: 2`

jqGrid display a total of 1 page! But if I disable the loadonce option, the total of page is set to 2 and it's perfect.

How can I make it works fine?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is by design.  The definition of the `loadonce` property, per the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) is:

> If this flag is set to true, the grid loads the data from the server
>   only once (using the appropriate datatype). **After the first request
>   the datatype parameter is automatically changed to local and all
>   further manipulations are done on the client side. The functions of
>   the pager (if present) are disabled.**

so, when `loadonce` is set to true, you will only load a single page from the server.  The only data that is now available is that which was loaded, so there is no page 2.

Comment: Thanks! You was more quickly as me. I agree with you and post my current answer only in the comment: "It is correct what jqGrid do. The `loadonce: true` means that the data for the grid will be **loaded once**. After the loading the `datatype` will be changed to `'local'` and the grid should ignore `url`. So the *local* paging of data will be used. All already loaded data can be only used. So the `records` or `total` value have to be discarded."